# How can I write self-modifying code on Windows?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm32, self-modifying

When I was learning to program in assembler on a DOS system - the program could change its own code while the program was running and see it in the debugger. For some reason it doesn't work on Windows. The debugger (OllyDbg) just stops the program and writes: debugged program was unable to process exception.

I read and found such a thing as file mapping, but I do not understand if I can edit the code on the go with this and if there are other methods. As far as I understand, I cannot use the usual methods because the attributes of pages or sections do not allow me to do this?

[image: Code example]

Comment: You're looking for VirtualProtect to change the page holding the .text section from read+exec to read+write+exec.  Normally the code section or your executable is mapped read-only in case of bugs and to defend against exploits that want to inject code.

Comment: Note that while writing self-modifying code is still a fun thing to do as an exercise, modern pipelining processors punish such shenanigans harshly in terms of performance, since it wreaks havoc on all those nice branch prediction algorithms and instruction caches and whatnot. When dynamic code is needed, it's far more common to write freshly-generated code into newly allocated pages specifically for that purpose, but even then those would not get modified afterwards.

Comment: @PeterCordes: For mapped sections, it's even more complicated than that, because read-only mappings are backed by the original executable binary instead of the swapfile (depending on whether there were relocations performed by the loader).  Merely calling VirtualProtect to make the RAM pages writable isn't enough, the paging configuration has to also be changed to private commit, or else the changes can be lost at any time.  Furthermore read+write+exec is not a valid combination of page access bits on modern W^X memory-management units.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Oh, interesting.  On POSIX OSes like Linux, a process is a `MAP_PRIVATE` mapping of the executable, so changes are copy-on-write and won't be lost.  That goes for the code as well as the read/write mappings, so self-modifying or a debugger using `PTRACE_POKETEXT` to turn instructions into breakpoints is only affecting that process.  Also, you're saying Windows prohibits W+X mappings?  The hardware certainly doesn't; W^X is only a good idea on most OSes, it's only the law on a few like OpenBSD.  And even then it's the OS's choice, not the hardware.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: It's normal to write new machine code into a new buffer, but that's mostly because the normal use case is JITing a whole function, not to avoid self-modifying-code (SMC) penalties.  On modern x86, the self-modifying-code penalty applies any time a store accesses a cache line that's already in the pipeline (already fetched). It nukes the pipeline (perf event `machine_clears.smc`), clearing the front-end and the ROB (out-of-order back-end).  (and yeah invalidates that line of I$) After that, everything runs normally unless there's another store. It doesn't hurt branch prediction.

Comment: If you have some code that's going to run many times per change (like tens of thousands), it could make sense for performance to modify it once with e.g. a new constant baked in, like a different shift count.  (Since shift by an amount in a register is less efficient on Intel, 3 uops, uless using BMI2 no-flags shifts.)  The penalty is bad, worse than a branch mispredict since those are handled specially, maybe similar to as an interrupt handler that did nothing and returned right away, or a CPUID instruction (but without a vm-exit if virtualized).

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes W^X is the OS's choice.  Windows lets the PE header recommend whether W^X is enforced, but ultimately the administrator has three choices (enforce W^X for ALL processes, respect the PE header, don't enforce for any processes).  You can't override that configuration locally with `VirtualProtect`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: And while copy-on-write is available in Windows virtual memory, you have to specifically ask for it.  Just read+write+exec won't do.

Comment: @BenVoigt If you make an image-backed code page writable on Windows, it is officially `PAGE_READWRITE` but internally it is a lazy copy, so effectively copy-on-write.

Comment: @RaymondChen: How does the caller distinguish between "image-backed, writable, commit back to disk" or "image-backed, writable, writes discardable" or "image-backed, on write becomes pagefile-backed"?  Is the difference whether the section was mapped in by the loader vs mapped in by `CreateFileMapping` ?  The documentation suggests the caller should specifically request `PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY` or `PAGE_WRITECOPY`

Comment: you can use `#pragma comment( linker, "/SECTION:.text,ERW" )` for make ".text" section writable.

Comment: Isn't this a risky prospect since pipelining can cause the CPU to be reading the value that used to be there before you changed it? Or am I mistaken?